# Doesn't have value in Array JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am going to ask why my array doesn't have a value when I already added. Here's my code in jquery adding value in array JQUERY.

**// ---- I set value inside array**

```
var arr= [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url+'joborder/select_account_details/',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $(".modal").show();
    },
    data: {date_added: date_added, ba: ba, service_type: custom},
    success: function (data) {
        $(".modal").hide();     
        if(data.length != 0) {
            $.each(JSON.parse(data),function(index,val) 
            {
                var values = {};
                values['id'] = val.id;  
                values['name'] = val.name;  
                values['address'] = val.address;    
                values['age'] = val.age;            
                arr.push(values);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**// ---    I started here to get the value I added in an array, but it returns an empty, I want to start appending data from here for not to load always the return data of ajax**

```
// var newval;
$.each(arr,function(key,row) 
{
    console.log(row);
    // newval += '<tr>';
    // newval += '<td></td>';
    // newval += '<td>'+row.id+'</td>';
    // newval += '<td>'+row.name+'</td>';
    // newval += '<td>'+row.address+'</td>';
    // newval += '<td>'+row.age+'</td>';
    // newval += '</tr>';
});
// $("#display_details tbody").append(newval);
```

Comment: where are you checking it?

Comment: i was checking the var arr if there's a value for me to loop outside an ajax success.

Comment: Most likely you try to access the array before the ajax is returned, therfor the array is still empty.

Comment: Are you sure `data` return any data? I mean *data from ajax* Also define `values` outside the loop

Comment: Danmoreng, how am I going to add the result ajax into a new array for me to access it outside the ajax?

Comment: Pedram, there's a return value. I want to add the return value in to a new array.

Comment: I need to put the datas inside array because of my Excel Like Bootstrap/exceltablefilter

Answer (score 0):

Make your ajax request as **synchronous** (blocking). Requests are **asynchronous** (non-blocking) by default which means that the browser won't wait for them to be completed in order to continue its work. That's why your `$.each` got wrong result. Add `async: false` to your ajax request as follows,

```
var arr= [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url+'joborder/select_account_details/',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $(".modal").show();
    },
    data: {date_added: date_added, ba: ba, service_type: custom},
    success: function (data) {
        $(".modal").hide();     
        if(data.length != 0) {
            $.each(JSON.parse(data),function(index,val) 
            {
                var values = {};
                values['id'] = val.id;  
                values['name'] = val.name;  
                values['address'] = val.address;    
                values['age'] = val.age;            
                arr.push(values);
            });
        }
    },
   async: false // this make it as synchronous
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are asynchronous, what that means is, your array won't be filled until the ajax request invokes a callback function. I encourage you to read more on asynchronous javascript.

What you could do in your case is something like this

```
function yourCallback(arr) {
    // here arr is filled and is ready to be used
    $.each(arr,function(key,row) {
        console.log(row);
        // newval += '<tr>';
        // newval += '<td></td>';
        // newval += '<td>'+row.id+'</td>';
        // newval += '<td>'+row.name+'</td>';
        // newval += '<td>'+row.address+'</td>';
        // newval += '<td>'+row.age+'</td>';
        // newval += '</tr>';
    });
    // $("#display_details tbody").append(newval);
}

function successCallback(data) {
    // function called when the ajax request completes with success
    var arr = [];
    $(".modal").hide();
    if(data.length != 0) {
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index,val) 
        {
            var values = {};
            values['id'] = val.id;  
            values['name'] = val.name;  
            values['address'] = val.address;    
            values['age'] = val.age;            
            arr.push(values);
        });
        yourCallback(arr);
    }
}

// the starting point of your code
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url+'joborder/select_account_details/',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $(".modal").show();
    },
    data: {date_added: date_added, ba: ba, service_type: custom},
    success: successCallback
});
```